# Задать description для страниц в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, текст, админка, контент

Каким образом можно добавлять и редактировать через админку description для некоторых страниц в WordPress?

```
<meta name="description" content="здесь добавляемый админом текст" />
```

Только без готовых плагинов.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен плагин для SEO-оптимизации, в WordPress сейчас без него никуда.

Рекомендую Yoast Seo, Rank Math, All in One SEO.

Для Rank Math description можно добавить здесь.

[image: Редактировать сниппет]

Comment: Как раз нужен вариант без плагинов. Вопрос отредактировала. Но все равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Irina Вас не устроит php скрипт?

Comment: с помощью php как раз и надо

Answer (score 0):

> Каким образом можно добавлять и редактировать через админку
> description для страниц в WordPress?

Для начала нужно понять, что description-а в WordPress нет.

Для реализации этой возможности наиболее простой и лучший вариант - использование [seo-плагинов](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/seo/). Кроме description-а они дадут ещё много других сеошных возможностей.

Другие варианты: использовать поле "[отрывок](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA)" или [произвольное поле](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) и вывести их в шаблонах используемой темы (в некоторых темы "отрывок" уже выводится в качестве description-а).

Answer (score 0):

> Взято с сайта [WP-kama.ru](https://wp-kama.ru/id_9537/seo-meta-tegi-bez-plaginov.html)

Создайте файл с именем class-Kama_SEO_Tags.php в корне вашей темы, в него скопируйте код:

```
<?php

/**
 * Simple SEO class for WordPress to create page metatags:
 * title, description, robots, keywords, Open Graph.
 *
 * IMPORTANT! Since version 1.7.0 robots code logic was chenged. Changed your code after update!
 * IMPORTANT! Since version 1.8.0 title code logic was chenged. Changed your code after update!
 *
 * @see https://github.com/doiftrue/Kama_SEO_Tags
 *
 * @author Kama
 *
 * @version 1.9.7
 */
class Kama_SEO_Tags {

    static function init(){

        // force WP document_title function to run
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
        add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', [ __CLASS__, 'meta_title' ], 1 );

        add_action( 'wp_head', [ __CLASS__, 'meta_description' ], 1 );
        add_action( 'wp_head', [ __CLASS__, 'meta_keywords' ], 1 );
        add_action( 'wp_head', [ __CLASS__, 'og_meta' ], 1 ); // Open Graph, twitter данные

        // WP 5.7+
        add_filter( 'wp_robots', [ __CLASS__, 'wp_robots_callback' ], 11 );
    }

    /**
     * Open Graph, twitter data in `<head>`.
     *
     * @See Documentation: http://ogp.me/
     */
    static function og_meta(){

        $obj = get_queried_object();

        if( isset( $obj->post_type ) )   $post = $obj;
        elseif( isset( $obj->term_id ) ) $term = $obj;

        $is_post = isset( $post );
        $is_term = isset( $term );

        $title = self::meta_title();
        $desc = preg_replace( '/^.+content="([^"]*)".*$/s', '$1', self::meta_description() );

        // Open Graph
        $els = [];
        $els['og:locale']      = get_locale();
        $els['og:site_name']   = get_bloginfo('name');
        $els['og:title']       = $title;
        $els['og:description'] = $desc;
        $els['og:type']        = is_singular() ? 'article' : 'object';

        // og:url
        if( 'url' ){

            if( $is_post ) $url = get_permalink( $post );
            if( $is_term ) $url = get_term_link( $term );

            if( ! empty( $url ) ){

                $els['og:url'] = $url;

                // relative (not allowed)
                if( '/' === $url[0] ){

                    // without protocol only: //domain.com/path
                    if( substr( $url, 0, 2 ) === '//' ){
                        $els['og:url'] = set_url_scheme( $url );
                    }
                    // without domain
                    else{
                        $parts = wp_parse_url( $url );
                        $els['og:url'] = home_url( $parts['path'] ) . ( isset( $parts['query'] ) ? "?{$parts['query']}" : '' );
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        /**
         * Allow to disable `article:section` property.
         *
         * @param bool $is_on
         */
        if( apply_filters( 'kama_og_meta_show_article_section', true ) ){

            if( is_singular() && $post_taxname =  get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type) ){

                $post_terms = get_the_terms( $post, reset($post_taxname) );
                if( $post_terms && $post_term = array_shift($post_terms) )
                    $els['article:section'] = $post_term->name;
            }
        }

        // og:image
        if( 'image' ){

            /**
             * Allow to change `og:image` `og:image:width` `og:image:height` values.
             *
             * @param int|string|array|WP_Post  $image_data  WP attachment ID or Image URL or Array [ image_url, width, height ].
             */
            $image = apply_filters( 'pre_kama_og_meta_image', null );

            if( ! $image ){

                $attach_id_from_text__fn = static function( $text ){

                    if(
                        preg_match( '/<img +src *= *[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/', $text, $mm )
                        &&
                        ( '/' === $mm[1][0] || strpos($mm[1], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) )
                    ){
                        $name = basename( $mm[1] );
                        $name = preg_replace( '~-[0-9]+x[0-9]+(?=\..{2,6})~', '', $name ); // удалим размер (-80x80)
                        $name = preg_replace( '~\.[^.]+$~', '', $name );                   // удалим расширение
                        $name = sanitize_title( sanitize_file_name( $name ) );

                        global $wpdb;
                        $attach_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
                            "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = 'attachment'", $name
                        ) );

                        return (int) $attach_id;
                    }

                    return 0;
                };

                if( $is_post ){

                    $image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );

                    if( ! $image ){

                        /**
                         * Allows to turn off the image search in post content.
                         *
                         * @param bool $is_on
                         */
                        if( apply_filters( 'kama_og_meta_thumb_id_find_in_content', true ) ){

                            // первое вложение поста
                            if( ! $image = $attach_id_from_text__fn( $post->post_content ) ) {

                                $attach = get_children([
                                    'numberposts'    => 1,
                                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                                ]);

                                if( $attach && $attach = array_shift( $attach ) )
                                    $image = $attach->ID;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                elseif( $is_term ){

                    $image = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, '_thumbnail_id', 1 );

                    if( ! $image )
                        $image = $attach_id_from_text__fn( $term->description );
                }

                /**
                 * Allow to set `og:image` `og:image:width` `og:image:height` values if it's not.
                 *
                 * @param int|string|array|WP_Post  $image_data  WP attachment ID or Image URL or Array [ image_url, width, height ].
                 */
                $image = apply_filters( 'kama_og_meta_image', $image );
                $image = apply_filters( 'kama_og_meta_thumb_id', $image ); // backcompat
            }

            if( $image ){

                if( $image instanceof WP_Post || is_numeric( $image ) ){

                    if( is_numeric( $image ) )
                        $image = get_post( $image );

                    if( $image ){

                        list(
                            $els['og:image[1]'],
                            $els['og:image[1]:width'],
                            $els['og:image[1]:height'],
                            $els['og:image[1]:alt'],
                            $els['og:image[1]:type']
                        ) = array_merge(
                            array_slice( image_downsize( $image->ID, 'full' ), 0, 3 ),
                            [ $image->post_excerpt, $image->post_mime_type ]
                        );

                        if( ! $els['og:image[1]:alt'] )
                            unset( $els['og:image[1]:alt'] );

                        // thumbnail
                        list(
                            $els['og:image[2]'],
                            $els['og:image[2]:width'],
                            $els['og:image[2]:height']
                        ) = array_slice( image_downsize( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' ), 0, 3 );
                    }
                }
                elseif( is_array( $image ) ){
                    list(
                        $els['og:image[1]'],
                        $els['og:image[1]:width'],
                        $els['og:image[1]:height']
                    ) = $image;
                }
                else{
                    $els['og:image[1]'] = $image;
                }

            }

        }

        // twitter
        $els['twitter:card'] = 'summary';
        $els['twitter:title'] = $els['og:title'];
        $els['twitter:description'] = $els['og:description'];
        if( ! empty( $els['og:image[1]'] ) ){
            $els['twitter:image'] = $els['og:image[1]'];
        }

        /**
         * Allows change values of og / twitter meta properties.
         *
         * @param array  $els
         */
        $els = apply_filters( 'kama_og_meta_elements_values', $els );
        $els = array_filter( $els );
        ksort( $els );

        // make <meta> tags
        $metas = [];
        foreach( $els as $key => $val ){

            // og:image[1] > og:image  ||  og:image[1]:width > og:image:width
            $fixed_key = preg_replace( '/\[\d\]/', '', $key );

            if( 0 === strpos( $key, 'twitter:' ) )
                $metas[] = '<meta name="' . $fixed_key . '" content="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
            else
                $metas[] = '<meta property="' . $fixed_key . '" content="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
        }

        /**
         * Filter resulting properties. Allows to add or remove any og/twitter properties.
         *
         * @param array  $els
         */
        $metas = apply_filters( 'kama_og_meta_elements', $metas, $els );

        echo "\n\n". implode( "\n", $metas ) ."\n\n";
    }

    /**
     * Generate string to show as document title.
     *
     * For posts and taxonomies specific title can be specified as metadata with name `title`.   *
     *
     * @param string $title `pre_get_document_title` passed value.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    static function meta_title( $title = '' ){
        global $post;

        // support for `pre_get_document_title` hook.
        if( $title )
            return $title;

        static $cache; if( $cache ) return $cache;

        $l10n = apply_filters( 'kama_meta_title_l10n', [
            '404'     => 'Ошибка 404: такой страницы не существует',
            'search'  => 'Результаты поиска по запросу: %s',
            'compage' => 'Комментарии %s',
            'author'  => 'Статьи автора: %s',
            'archive' => 'Архив за',
            'paged'   => 'Страница %d',
        ] );

        $parts = [
            'prev'  => '',
            'title' => '',
            'page'  => '',
            'after' => '',
        ];

        // 404
        if( is_404() ){
            $parts['title'] = $l10n['404'];
        }
        // search
        elseif( is_search() ){
            $parts['title'] = sprintf( $l10n['search'], get_query_var( 's' ) );
        }
        // front_page
        elseif( is_front_page() ){

            if( is_page() && $parts['title'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', 1 ) ){
                // $parts['title'] defined
            }
            else {
                $parts['title'] = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
                $parts['after'] = '{{description}}';
            }
        }
        // singular
        elseif( is_singular() || ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) || ( is_page() && ! is_front_page() ) ){

            $parts['title'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', 1 );

            if( ! $parts['title'] ){
                /**
                 * Allow to set meta title for singular type page, before the default title will be taken.
                 *
                 * @param string  $title
                 * @param WP_Post $post
                 */
                $parts['title'] = apply_filters( 'kama_meta_title_singular', '', $post );
            }

            if( ! $parts['title'] )
                $parts['title'] = single_post_title( '', 0 );

            if( $cpage = get_query_var( 'cpage' ) )
                $parts['prev'] = sprintf( $l10n['compage'], $cpage );
        }
        // post_type_archive
        elseif( is_post_type_archive() ){
            $parts['title'] = post_type_archive_title('', 0 );
            $parts['after'] = '{{blog_name}}';
        }
        // taxonomy
        elseif( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ){
            $term = get_queried_object();

            $parts['title'] = $term ? get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'title', 1 ) : '';

            if( ! $parts['title'] ){
                $parts['title'] = single_term_title('', 0 );

                if( is_tax() )
                    $parts['prev'] = get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy )->labels->name;
            }

            $parts['after'] = '{{blog_name}}';
        }
        // author posts archive
        elseif( is_author() ){
            $parts['title'] = sprintf( $l10n['author'], get_queried_object()->display_name );
            $parts['after'] = '{{blog_name}}';
        }
        // date archive
        elseif( ( get_locale() === 'ru_RU' ) && ( is_day() || is_month() || is_year() ) ){
            $rus_month = [
                '', 'январь', 'февраль', 'март', 'апрель', 'май', 'июнь',
                'июль', 'август', 'сентябрь', 'октябрь', 'ноябрь', 'декабрь'
            ];
            $rus_month2 = [
                '', 'января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня',
                'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'
            ];
            $year     = get_query_var('year');
            $monthnum = get_query_var('monthnum');
            $day      = get_query_var('day');

            if( is_year() )      $dat = "$year год";
            elseif( is_month() ) $dat = "{$rus_month[ $monthnum ]} $year года";
            elseif( is_day() )   $dat = "$day {$rus_month2[ $monthnum ]} $year года";

            $parts['title'] = sprintf( $l10n['archive'], $dat );
            $parts['after'] = '{{blog_name}}';
        }
        // other archives
        else {
            $parts['title'] = get_the_archive_title();
            $parts['after'] = '{{blog_name}}';
        }

        // pagination
        $pagenum = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ?: get_query_var( 'page' );
        if( $pagenum && ! is_404() ){
            $parts['page'] = sprintf( $l10n['paged'], $pagenum );
        }

        /**
         * Allows to change parts of the document title.
         *
         * @param array $parts Title parts. It then will be joined.
         * @param array $l10n  Localisation strings.
         */
        $parts = apply_filters( 'kama_meta_title_parts', $parts, $l10n );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
        $parts = apply_filters( 'document_title_parts', $parts );

        // handle placeholders
        if( '{{blog_name}}' === $parts['after'] ){
            $parts['after'] = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
        }
        elseif( '{{description}}' === $parts['after'] ){
            $parts['after'] = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
        $sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', ' — ' );

        $title = implode( ' '. trim( $sep ) .' ', array_filter( $parts ) );

        $title = wptexturize( $title );
        $title = convert_chars( $title );
        $title = esc_html( $title );
        $title = capital_P_dangit( $title );

        return $cache = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Display `description` metatag.
     *
     * Must be used on hook `wp_head`.
     *
     * Use `description` meta-field to set description for any posts.
     * It also work for page setted as front page.
     *
     * Use `meta_description` meta-field to set description for any terms.
     * Or use default `description` field of a term.
     *
     * @return string Description.
     */
    static function meta_description(){

        // called from `wp_head` hook
        $echo_result = ( func_num_args() === 1 );

        static $cache = null;
        if( isset( $cache ) ){

            if( $echo_result )
                echo $cache;

            return $cache;
        }

        global $post;

        $desc = '';
        $need_cut = true;

        // front
        if( is_front_page() ){

            // когда для главной установлена страница
            if( is_page() ){
                $desc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'description', true );
                $need_cut = false;
            }

            if( ! $desc ){

                /**
                 * Allow to change front_page meta description.
                 *
                 * @param string $home_description
                 */
                $desc = apply_filters( 'home_meta_description', get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ) );
            }
        }
        // any post
        elseif( is_singular() ){

            if( $desc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'description', true ) ){
                $need_cut = false;
            }

            if( ! $desc ){
                $desc = $post->post_excerpt ?: $post->post_content;
            }

            $desc = trim( strip_tags( $desc ) );
        }
        // any term (taxonomy element)
        elseif( ( $term = get_queried_object() ) && ! empty( $term->term_id ) ){

            $desc = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'meta_description', true );

            if( ! $desc )
                $desc = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'description', true );

            $need_cut = false;
            if( ! $desc && $term->description ){
                $desc = strip_tags( $term->description );
                $need_cut = true;
            }
        }

        $desc = str_replace( [ "\n", "\r" ], ' ', $desc );

        // remove shortcodes, but leave markdown [foo](URL)
        $desc = preg_replace( '~\[[^\]]+\](?!\()~', '', $desc );

        /**
         * Allow change or set the meta description.
         *
         * @param string $desc        Current description.
         * @param string $origin_desc Description before cut.
         * @param bool   $need_cut    Is need to cut?
         * @param int    $maxchar     How many characters leave after cut.
         */
        $desc = apply_filters( 'kama_meta_description', $desc );

        /**
         * Allow to specify is the meta description need to be cutted.
         *
         * @param bool $need_cut
         */
        $need_cut = apply_filters( 'kama_meta_description__need_cut', $need_cut );

        if( $need_cut ){

            /**
             * Allow set max length of the meta description.
             *
             * @param int $maxchar
             */
            $maxchar = apply_filters( 'kama_meta_description__maxchar', 260 );

            $char = mb_strlen( $desc );

            if( $char > $maxchar ){
                $desc = mb_substr( $desc, 0, $maxchar );
                $words = explode( ' ', $desc );
                $maxwords = count( $words ) - 1; // remove last word, it incomplete in 90% cases
                $desc = implode( ' ', array_slice( $words, 0, $maxwords ) ) . ' ...';
            }
        }

        // remove multi-space
        $desc = preg_replace( '/\s+/s', ' ', $desc );

        $cache = $desc
            ? sprintf( "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"%s\" />\n", esc_attr( trim( $desc ) ) )
            : '';

        if( $echo_result )
            echo $cache;

        return $cache;
    }

    /**
     * Wrpper for WP Robots API introduced in WP 5.7+.
     *
     * Must be used on hook `wp_robots`.
     *
     * @param array $robots
     */
    static function wp_robots_callback( $robots ){

        if( is_singular() ){
            $robots_str = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'robots', true );
        }
        elseif( is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
            $robots_str = get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'robots', true );
        }

        if( ! empty( $robots_str ) ){

            // split by spece or comma
            $robots_parts = preg_split( '/(?<!:)[\s,]+/', $robots_str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

            foreach( $robots_parts as $directive ){

                // for max-snippet:2
                if( strpos( $directive, ':' ) ){
                    list( $key, $value ) = explode( ':', $directive );
                    $robots[ $key ] = $value;
                }
                else {
                    $robots[ $directive ] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if( ! empty( $robots['none'] ) || ! empty( $robots['noindex'] ) ){
            unset( $robots['max-image-preview'] );
        }

        return $robots;
    }

    /**
     * Generate `<meta name="keywords">` meta-tag fore <head> part of the page.
     *
     * To set Your own keywords for post, create meta-field with key `keywords`
     * and set the keyword to the value.
     *
     * Default keyword for a post generates from post tags nemes and categories names.
     * If the `keywords` meta-field is not specified.
     *
     * You can specify the keywords for the any taxonomy element (term) using shortcode
     * `[keywords=word1, word2, word3]` in the description field.
     *
     * @param string $home_keywords Keywords for home page. Ex: 'word1, word2, word3'
     * @param string $def_keywords  сквозные ключевые слова - укажем и они будут прибавляться
     *                              к остальным на всех страницах.
     */
    static function meta_keywords( $home_keywords = '', $def_keywords = '' ){
        global $post;

        $out = [];

        if( is_front_page() ){
            $out[] = $home_keywords;
        }
        elseif( is_singular() ){

            $meta_keywords = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'keywords', true );

            if( $meta_keywords ){
                $out[] = $meta_keywords;
            }
            elseif( $post->post_type === 'post' ){

                $res = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, [ 'post_tag', 'category' ], [ 'orderby' => 'none' ] );

                if( $res && ! is_wp_error( $res ) ){
                    foreach( $res as $tag ){
                        $out[] = $tag->name;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        elseif( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ){
            $term = get_queried_object();

            // wp 4.4
            if( function_exists( 'get_term_meta' ) && $term ){
                $out[] = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'keywords', true );
            }
            else{
                preg_match( '!\[keywords=([^\]]+)\]!iU', $term->description, $match );
                $out[] = isset( $match[1] ) ? trim( $match[1] ) : '';
            }
        }

        if( $def_keywords ){
            $out[] = $def_keywords;
        }

        echo $out
            ? '<meta name="keywords" content="'. implode( ', ', $out ) .'" />' . "\n"
            : '';
    }

}
```

В functons.php пропишите:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/seo.php';

Kama_SEO_Tags::init();
```

Comment: Смешно. Вы хоть читайте что человеку надо. Вы даже не переспросили нужно ли ей **meta_keywords** и **og_meta**. Кроме того, на странице этого куска, есть сноска : **Как создать метабоксы с метаполями?
Сделать это можно с помощью класса Kama_Post_Meta_Box, просто кодом или с помощью плагинов Carbon Fields, Meta Box.** Это значит, что код без мета полей  - чемодан без ручки. Нафиг вывод того, чего нет и ввести нет возможности? Вы можете возразить, "она поймёт"... смеюсь очень громко... не уверен. Тут люди ищут готовые решения, от и до (скопировал, вставил).

Comment: @Sergio Спасибо за замечание, дополню, как появится время.

Comment: приятно видеть сдержанного, воспитанного человека. Респект и уважуха Вам.